# Special characters for dialing

Tags: android, urlencode

In Brazil, we use # to make some types of calls. For example, see the balance of a prepaid account phone, something like this: *222#

I use this code to call:

```
public static void doCall(Context context, String number) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
    context.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Android removes # automatically? Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks, 
Mateus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL-escape the '#', by using '%23' in its place:

```
tel:*222%23
```